# Conflict in showing the Linear Layout when the QWERTY keypad is shown

Tags: android, xml, android-keypad, android-input-method

I have a layout that looks like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginRight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:fontFamily="@font/tahoma"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="SAMPLE HEADER"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#e7e6e6"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/buttons"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">




        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="4sp"
            android:layout_above="@id/bot_nav"
            android:background="@drawable/shadow" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/buttons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/alt_gray"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_save"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tahoma"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="17sp"
                    android:text="Save"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="true">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/tahoma"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="17sp"
                    android:text="Cancel"
                    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

this is what it looks

[image]

and sometimes when the keypad is shown this is what it looks.

[image]

How can I fix this issue? Does it varies on the phone because when i try it on other phone the layout is ok but on others it is not. how can i fix this issue? I know there are a lot of improper layout on my file. sorry on that.

Comment: try removing padding and make sure only fonts have size in `sp`, in othercase use `dp`

Comment: @SujinShrestha what padding?

Comment: Its basically space inside your view. check your code. there are many paddings used